# Can we configure IBM clear case in sonar for analysis for project?

Tags: sonarqube, clearcase

Can we use sonar tool in IBM rational clearcase to generate analysis report,If yes how to configure sonar for IBM rational clearcase?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent sonarqb integration is based on Jazz Engine instead of ClearCase (see "[Integrate SonarQube into a DevOps environment](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/integrate-sonarqube-devops-environment/index.html)")

That being said, it is possible for a Sonar instance to query code from ClearCase for analysis, using for instance the [ClearCase Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/ClearCase+Plugin) and the property `-Dsonar.scm.provider=clearcase`.

As this [thread mentions](http://markmail.org/message/xc5fuqx22asaqwoy#query:+page:1+mid:xc5fuqx22asaqwoy+state:results), if you are using a [sonnar-runner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner), you would  specify the location of this code using the `sonar.sources` variable.

Comment: Can you please tell me where do i need to mention this property Dsonar.scm.provider=clearcase property, is it in sonar.propertie file . I didnt find clearcase plugin in sonar update center

Comment: @YaminiIrla https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scm-clearcase. the `sonar.scm.provider` is a java property that you set in your java option `-Dsonar.scm.provider=xxx` (since 5.0: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/f84e08449a133657226a78f26a3eee724e0210ea/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/CoreProperties.java#L557-L560)